# Printing values of stat() command with print() in perl

Tags: perl

I need to see what stat() command is returning. How can i do that ? I used the following, but it didn't work :-

```
print(stat($filename"));
```

I mean the command got executed, but it did not print the value that stat must have returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html:

```
($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
       $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
           = stat($filename);
```

---

Also,

> The File::stat module provides a convenient, by-name access mechanism:

```
use File::stat;
$sb = stat($filename);
printf "File is %s, size is %s, perm %04o, mtime %s\n",
       $filename, $sb->size, $sb->mode & 07777,
       scalar localtime $sb->mtime;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just the raw output? `stat` returns a list.

```
print (join (",", (stat($filename))), "\n");
```

Comment: if your command doesn't work, does it mean stat returned null ?

Comment: Try adding a "die $!". It could be simply a typo or something. Is `$filename` a full pathname or relative?

Answer (score 2):

If you ever want to debug data structures in perl I recommend the Dumper tool as invaluable.

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper(stat($filename));
```

will give the output:

```
$VAR1 = 89;
$VAR2 = 1394949;
$VAR3 = 33188;
$VAR4 = 1;
$VAR5 = 1000;
$VAR6 = 20;
$VAR7 = 5574438;
$VAR8 = 100;
$VAR9 = 1320421684;
$VAR10 = 1317166549;
$VAR11 = 1317166549;
$VAR12 = 4096;
$VAR13 = 4;
```

perldoc Data::Dumper for details on the options and settings of this module.

Comment: Also if your stat is failing in the above example you'd end up with a Dumper output of `$VAR1 = undef` meaning it returned an undefined result.